# Обрубка русского текста

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь вывести предложение с указанным искомым словом, но программа не выводит полностью всё предложение, а лишь часть текста.

```
    while (1)
{
    int begining_pos = text.find(search); // начало строки
    int crt_pos;                          // текущая позиция

    crt_pos = text.find(search); // ищу позицию искомого слова
    if (crt_pos == -1)
        break;
        // если предложений с таким словом нет, 
                                  // то выхожу из цикла

                                  // ищу начало строки
    for (int i = crt_pos; ; i--)
    {
        if (text[i] != '!' && text[i] != '.' && text[i] != '?' && i != 0)
            begining_pos--;
        else
        {
            crt_pos = i;
            if (crt_pos > 0)
                begining_pos++; // начало строки
            break;
        }
    }
    // записываю строку
    for (crt_pos = begining_pos; ; crt_pos++)
    {
        if (text[crt_pos] == '!' || text[crt_pos] == '.' || text[crt_pos] == '?' || (int)text[crt_pos] == -1)
        {
            result += text[crt_pos];
            break;
        }

        if (crt_pos == begining_pos && text[crt_pos] == ' ') continue;
        result += text[crt_pos]; // записал строку в 'result'
    }

    // вывожу результат
    cout << result << endl << endl;

    text.erase(begining_pos, crt_pos + 1); // удаляю из текста найденую строку
    result = ""; // очищаю результат
}
```

Вот пример:
[image: Обрубка русского текста]

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
string text = ""; // текст записанный из файла
string search;    // искомое слово
string result;    // результат поиска
string filename = "rus.txt"; // имя файла

                              // файл в котором будет осуществляться поиск
ifstream *in = new ifstream(filename.data());
if (in->fail())
{
    cout << "Файл '" << filename << "' не найден! " << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}

// пользователь вводит искомое слово
cout << "Введите искомое слово: ";
cin >> search;

// записываю содержимое файла
if (in->is_open())
{
    while (!in->eof())
        text += in->get();

    in->close();
}
delete in;
```

Вот описание всех строк и начало программы.

Comment: SetConsoleCP(1251);
 SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
Присутствуют

Comment: Мне кажется, что эта проблема решается исключительно дебаггером - шаг за шагом.

Comment: может вы сами обрезаете конец строки

Comment: Приведите минимальную программу, воспроизводящую проблему. Почему Вы считаете, что здесь работают телепаты? Что такое `text`? Объект STL `string`? Почему тогда Вы пользуетесь функцией `find()`, но не пользуетесь поиском символов `find_first_of(), find_last_of()` и т.п. из `string`? Зачем работаете с С++ строками, будто это строки Си? Программа стала бы компактнее и было бы меньше мест для ошибок.

Comment: @Vladimir, я добавил начало программы.

Comment: Кодировка в консоли - это одно. В какой кодировке файл?

Comment: @vp_arth CP 1251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, как и сказал предыдущий оратор, в ANSI cp1251 буква 'я' имеет код при приведении к знаковому типу "-1".

Виновата строка при "записи":

```
if (text[crt_pos] == '!' || text[crt_pos] == '.' || text[crt_pos] == '?' || (int)text[crt_pos] == -1)
```

Если убрать последнее условие (|| (int)text[crt_pos] == -1 ), то предложение выводится полностью. А вот зачем было нужно это условия, я пока не стал выяснять.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII "я" в cp1251 имеет код 255, что тождественно -1 в `signed char`

Вы можете сравнивать `crt_pos` с длиной строки, например

Comment: Тут дело в том, что программа не доходит до конца, она обрубается с ошибкой string is out of range. Нужно скорее всего менять кодировку (наверное), я где-то вычитал, что русские символы занимают в 2 раза больше места и видимо ей не хватает